# How can I find $F (2, 3)$ . Linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that $$F(1, 0) = (1, 2, 3) \\ F(0, 1)= (0, 0, 0)$$ Find $F (2, 3)$.

In the answer, we need to write down an element of a linear space in the notation that is introduced in this problem. Example: $(1, 2, 3)$. 
How can I find these coordinates? What i should do? Get me hint, 
please.

Comment: Linearity allows you to do the following: $$F(a,b)=aF(1,0)+bF(0,1)$$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Therefore, F(2;3) = 2(1;2;3) + 3(0;0;0) = (2;4;6). Is this the right solution?

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: @Aleksandr It should be clear to you that the equation written by Dave follows from the fact that $(a,b)=a(1,0)+b(0,1)$ and the linearity of $F$.